# Searching jar or tar from bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, piping

This seems like a simple bash task, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  In this particular instance it is in regards to the jar command, but is equally applicable to the tar command.

Enough set up, here's the question:

I use the following bash command to search for a file within a jar:

```
jar -tf com.my.jarfile.jar | grep some_search_text
```

Simple enough.  Now, I have a directory of jar files, and what I would really like is a command which can tell me which jars contain a file whose name contains a given string.  Is this possible?

Background Problem:  I have a file which has accidentally proliferated through a few jar files in my project.  I would like to determine which jar files contain this file.  The command above is a little different in that it will output files from the jar that match the pattern.  I am less interested in knowing the names of the matching files within the jar as I am just which jars contain matches.

Comment: What your command looks for is file names within the jar file that contain 'some_search_text'.  Are you looking for jar files which contain the string, or jar files which contain a file where the file name contains the string?  The processing is quite different.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution which looks for **file names** in jar files recursively, you can have a look at this shell script as a starting point: https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/blob/master/Shell/bash/grepJar

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ambiguity.  I am looking for the latter, any jar files which contain a file whose name contains the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're interested in the jar files which contain files where the file name matches your target string, you can write a simple loop:

```
search="some_search_text"
for file in *.jar
do
    echo "$file"
    jar -tf "$file" | grep -e "$search"
done
```

This will echo each jar file's name, and then if the jar file contains a file whose name matches the search string, that will be shown.  The `-e` ensures that there's no confusion even if your search string starts with a dash.

If you don't want the non-matching names to appear, then:

```
search="some_search_text"
for file in *.jar
do
    match=$(jar -tf "$file" | grep -e "$search")
    if [ -n "$match" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
        echo "$match"
    fi
done
```

And if you simply want the jar file name to appear if it contains a file whose name matches, then (obviously):

```
search="some_search_text"
for file in *.jar
do
    match=$(jar -tf "$file" | grep -e "$search")
    if [ -n "$match" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Though that can be shrunk to:

```
search="some_search_text"
for file in *.jar
do
    [ -n "$(jar -tf "$file" | grep -e "$search")" ] && echo "$file"
done
```

Both the jar and tar commands process one of their files per invocation; there isn't a way to have a single invocation process multiple files.

If you're really interested in jar files where the jar file contains anything that matches your search text, then you can use:

```
search="some_search_text"

grep -e "$search" -l *.jar
```

The `-l` lists the jar files by name.  This works sanely even though the typical jar file contains binary data.

Comment: Turns out your simple grep command at the end was sufficient to get me an answer.  Your loops above will definitely also come in handy, and do more accurately address the question as stated. Thanks!

Comment: Your last update had not appeared when I accepted this.  Consider this comment a second upvote.